# How to create button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, custom-painting

How do you create this button in this way? Need for my academic work. Please help me!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njwoJ.png)

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
   ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  backgroundColor: green,
                  shadowColor: green,
                  elevation: 3,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                  minimumSize: const Size(100, 50),
                ),
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Arabic",
                    style: forteenWhite,
                  ),
                )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Container(
              width: 300,
              height: 60,
              color: const Color(0xFF9c1f5d),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child:
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    'Register your account today !',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black
                    )
                  ),            
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: const Color(0xFFcc4e8c),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(                 
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), 
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
  padding: Padding.Edgeall(10.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  height: 55,
  child: Text("This is button")
),
```

And to use onClick wrap the Text or container with InkWell.